# java xml parsing a large file and db relation

Tags: java, xml

I have a 10+ MB xml file with consists of node(about 10K to 20K) with relations.

```
<.....>
<Emplyoyee>
    <name>Jack</name>
    <age>35</age>
    <supervisor></supervisor>
    <....>
</Emplyoyee>
<.....>
<.....>
<.....>
<Emplyoyee>
    <name>Smith</name>
    <age>20</age>
    <supervisor>Jack</supervisor>
    <....>
</Emplyoyee>
<.....>
```

Now, I want to parse this file and store all the details in DB with "Employee" table which has a field(ID) called "supervisorID". Until now I have tried to make a List of all the employees and then iterating the List for finding supervisor relation.

Please suggest me a memory efficient and faster way to do this. What libraries can I use to handle this type of problems.

Comment: you mean you have parsed it using, lets say the `Documentfactory` in java, but you need a more efficient way?

Comment: What happens when you have two "emplyoyees" [sic] with the same name and both are supervisors?  How to you link their subordinates to the correct one?

Comment: @JimGarrison The employee names correspond to xxxx in xxxx@xyz.com so are unique. I've put these names for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert data from `XML` file to Java Objects using `JAXB` and insert Java objects to database using `Hibernate` + `JPA`.
You can create 2 DTO
`Emplyoyee` - with all info about Emplyoyee (name, age, ...)
and
`Emplyoyees` with `List<Emplyoyee>` for JAXB unmarshalling

**EDIT: WITHOUT JAXB and JPA**

You can parse file using **javascript** and send **SQL** queries usinf **Ajax**

```
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML.DOMDocument");  
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = true;
xmlDoc.load(pathToFile);
var nodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes("/Emplyoyee");  
for (var node = nodes.nextNode(); node != null; node = nodes.nextNode())
{
   // get another nodes, create SQL query and sent it to server usinj Ajax  
}
```

Comment: When using JAXB xjc does most of the work for you. There are many tools that will create an XSD for you given a file sample which will get you most of what you need to use with JAXB (I tend to use the XML tools in intelliJ: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generating-xml-schema-from-instance-document.html). JAXB is more than capable of doing this for a 10MB file, I perform a similar task on a 30MB file to get daily supplier updates. Oh and here is a good JAXB primer http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html

Comment: You can also start from the JPA entities and add JAXB annotations to map those classes to the desired XML format.

Comment: I could not use Hibernate for some reasons, and I want it to be done with in 5 secs (Parsing + Persistence) and thought of threads to make it faster persistence but the fact that I need to parse all the nodes before searching for relations. Also the number of employees entities may grow to 50K-60K.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [**MOXy**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy) framework provided by *EclipseLink*. It uses **JAXB** implementation behind the scenes in fact. But does also the ORM stuff with **JPA**.